# Fetch Error using imaplib

Tags: python

I am writing a script to go through my email to calculate how much money I have spent in total on Uber rides. (Uber sends you a receipt to your email which includes the cost. I am going through the emails to find the cost, and then adding it to the array currently) I had it functioning for tests using 1 email, but am running into an issue whilst trying to loop through all of the emails.

I know that `id_list`(list of email ids) is a full array. When I print it out, I receive: `['4726', '5543', '5587', '5589', '5661', '5758', '5759', '5853', '5986', '6071', '6072', '6076', '6105', '6141', '6229']`

Here is my full error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Harrison/Desktop/Uber/Uber.py", line 22, in <module>
    result,data = mail.fetch(id, "(RFC822")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 456, in fetch
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, message_set, message_parts)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1088, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 918, in _command_complete
    raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.error: FETCH command error: BAD ['Could not parse command']
```

And here is my code:

```
import imaplib
import email
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

final_cost1 = ""
final_cost2 = ""

cost_array = []

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('my email', 'my passowrd')

mail.list()
mail.select('inbox')
result,data = mail.search(None, 'FROM', '"Uber Receipts"')

ids = data[0]
id_list = ids.split()


for id in id_list:
    result,data = mail.fetch(id, "(RFC822")

    message_body = data[0][1]

    uber_email = email.message_from_string(message_body)
    for part in uber_email.walk():
        if part.get_content_type() == "text/html":
            body = part.get_payload(None, decode=True)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
    #print soup.prettify()

    for row in soup.find_all('td', attrs={"class" : "price final-charge"}):
        final_cost1 = row.text.lstrip().strip()

    for row in soup.find_all('td', attrs={"class" : "totalPrice chargedFare black"}):
        final_cost2 = row.text.lstrip().strip()

    if final_cost1 != "":
        print final_cost1
        cost_array.append(final_cost1)
    if final_cost2 != "":
        print final_cost2
        cost_array.append(final_cost2)

print cost_array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake on my part.

This line `result,data = mail.fetch(id, "(RFC822")` had a typo. It should have been `result,data = mail.fetch(id, "(RFC822)")`